# HTML / CSS -Arrow is under the carousel

Tags: html, css, position

Hi I'm beginner and I need some help with my carousel for my web page. I have made 2 arrows and the left arrow is under the carousel. How can I move it in front? Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd0UY.jpg)

HTML

```
<button class="btn left-btn hide">
            <img src="img/left-arrow.svg" alt="">
        </button>
```

CSS

```
.left-btn {
    left: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use z-index to bring the element forward. You can for example set a large z-index to bring your left arrow forward:

```
.left-btn {
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

"The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order."

Quoted from: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: If it helps, it would be nice if you could accept or upvote the answer :) Thank you Saksorn!